# Problems when sorting a Google sheet that someone else is editing

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

In the past, when two people were editing the same Google sheet, if person A attempted to do a sort they would get a "heads-up" warning that A's sort was going to affect person B.

We now don't seem to get that heads-up message anymore, but we frequently have cases where if person A sorts while person B is editing a cell, the edits go into the wrong cell ... i.e., they go into the ***physical*** row and column that B was initially editing, but because of the sort, this is no longer the correct destination for the edits.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What is the question? P.S. Show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to sort the sheet instead of using **Data > Sort**. This feature lets multiple simultaneous users sort, filter and edit the sheet without disturbing each other.

For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Filter views only mask filter criteria from other users; sorting within a filter view will also affect the unfiltered view for others.  ( based on my own trial and error in attempts to isolate sort changes affecting other users )

P.S. lack rep points to add as comment instead of answer; sorry in advance.